# My texture won't show up on the object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, blend-files

I am designing a simple tent in Blender. I created a prism from a cube. Then, I added a material and a texture, and UV-unwrapped the prism. But the texture won't show up on the prism. I made double sure I had enabled material / texture mode in the view mode - that didn't help. [Here](https://easyupload.io/p9qju8) is the blend file with the texture included - I really tried everything I could find in the internet to make that texture show up, but without succes … You are my last hope … Apologies if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the shader what texture to put on the cube.  Add a Texture Coordinate node and an Image Texture node to your shader:

[image: Image texture and texture coordinate nodes added]